# Find difference between time in php

Tags: php, time, timestamp

I need to find the different between 2 timestamp values ,how to calculate it

```
$time1 ='2016-08-31T07:00:00';
$time2 ='2016-08-31T08:45:00';

I need output time value as 1h 45m
```

How to get desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date_a = new DateTime('2016-08-31T07:00:00');
$date_b = new DateTime('2016-08-31T08:45:00');

$interval = date_diff($date_a,$date_b);

echo $interval->format('%h Hours:%i Min:%s sec');
```

You Can test the code [Here](http://phpfiddle.org/)

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php
$time1 ='2016-08-31T07:00:00';
$time2 ='2016-08-31T08:45:00';
$d = strtotime($time2) - strtotime($time1);
echo gmdate("g", $d),'h ',gmdate('i',$d),'m ';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `strtotime()` to convert datetime in timestamps and get the difference between 2 times.

Now, Divide the difference into desire format. Use below code.

```
$time1 ='2016-08-31T07:00:00';
$time2 ='2016-08-31T08:45:00';
$diff = abs(strtotime($time1) - strtotime($time2));

$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));
$hours   = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24)/ (60*60)); 
$minuts  = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24 - $hours*60*60)/ 60); 
$seconds = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24 - $hours*60*60 - $minuts*60)); 

echo $hours . "h " .$minuts."m";
```

**Output**

```
1h 45m
```

**Live Demo : [Click Here](https://eval.in/584429)**

Comment: Use above code to get your desire result. @vellai durai

Answer (score 0):

Use this code,

```
$datetime1 = strtotime("09:00");
$datetime2 = strtotime($items['duration']);
$interval  = abs($datetime2 - $datetime1);
$min   = round($interval / 60);
$d = floor ($min / 1440);
$h = floor (($min - $d * 1440) / 60);
$m = $min - ($d * 1440) - ($h * 60);
if (!$m) {
  $m = '00';
}
echo $h."h:".$m."m";
```